# how can i have my sql show the sum of 2 tables at the same time?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I've tried to show the result of sum of bill total and vat total (that customer paid VAT) and the sum of all(bill_total + vat) for monthly.  However, my sql command show nothing after it executed. So could you kindly please help me as my sql knowledge was so limit.

My tables are below

**tbl_bill_total**

```
bill_id | bill_total | cust_id | showndate 
  1     |   1000     |   12    |  12/10/13
  2     |   1200     |   13    |  1/11/13
  3     |   500      |   12    |  3/11/13
```

**tbl_vat_bill_total**

```
vat_id  |  vat_total |  if_paid| showndate | cust_id 
  1     |    400     |   false |  13/10/13 |  14
  2     |    500     |   true  |  14/11/13 |  12
  3     |    100     |   false |  15/11/13 |  11
  4     |    200     |   true  |  20/11/13 |  12
```

The expected result should be like this

```
bill_total  |  vat_total | Sum_of_all | month
  1000      |    0       |   1000     |  10
  1700      |    700     |   2400     |  11
```

Thank you very much

** sorry I've changed the expected result… As it is a yearly report, so the outcome should list all sales in one year. ***

below is my attempt that failed...

```
SELECT 
    Sum(tbl_bill_total.bill_total) AS bill_totalOfSum, 
    Sum(tbl_vat_bill_total.vat_total) AS vat_totalOfSum, 
    tbl_vat_bill_total.if_paid, 
    Month([tbl_bill_total.showndate]) AS month1
FROM 
    tbl_bill_total 
    INNER JOIN 
    tbl_vat_bill_total 
        ON tbl_bill_total.cust_id = tbl_vat_bill_total.cust_id
GROUP BY 
    tbl_vat_bill_total.if_paid, 
    Month([tbl_bill_total.showndate])
HAVING (((tbl_vat_bill_total.if_paid)=True));
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a paid vat total in month without a corresponding bill total in the same month? Oh and what was your attempt?

Comment: I've tried to create a yearly report that show the revenue of sales that had non-vat and vat (that client have paid to us (if_paid = true)) of each month and show the sum of this 2 values at the same time.

Comment: I gathered that already, are there always two values was my question. If there are, a left join on Month(shownDate) would work, if however you can have a vat record in a month with no corresponding bill in that month, more querying is required, as in left join union right join. Or a temporary table/intermediate query..

Comment: no.. some month there would be no vat_total. Could you please give me the sql command ? as I mentioned earlier my sql knowledge is really limit. Though I understand its logic of how to retrieve but I can't come up with its syntax and command. thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, i've my output changed. and this new samples of records should explain more in what I want from this outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I haven't used Access in awhile, but I think the following should work:

```
select 
    sum(tbt.bill_total) as bill_total_
    ,iif(sum_vat_total is null, 0, sum_vat_total) as vat_total_
    ,iif(sum_vat_total is null, 0, sum_vat_total) + sum(bill_total) as sum_of_all
    ,month(showndate) as month
from tbl_bill_total tbt
left join (
    select 
        sum(vat_total) as sum_vat_total
        ,month(showndate) as month
    from tbl_vat_bill_total
    where if_paid = true
        and year(showndate) = 2013
    group by 
        month(showndate)
    ) tvt
        on tvt.month = month(tbt.showndate) 
where year(showndate) = 2013
group by 
    month(showndate)
    ,sum_vat_total
```

Of course, this assumes that you will at least have one record per month in `tbl_bill_total` since that is the source of our `month` field.

If you have months where there are `tbl_vat_bill_total` records but no `tbl_bill_total` records (or no records in either table), you will need a more complex solution - likely with a [date table](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/).

Comment: So what was the errror?

Comment: @Alxan I copied and pasted that query into Access 2010 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Sorry! my mistake. It's work. however how can i have only result that came from year 2013 only? I've tried to put condition of year to the statement but I failed. thank you very much.

Comment: Add where year(ShownDate) = 2013 to the first select (before the last group By), then add  and year(ShownDate) = 2013 to the second.

Comment: Alxan and @Tony I have updated the post per the new requirement and suggestion. This should now only sum transactions in 2013

Comment: You are quite welcome! Would you kindly accept whichever answer ultimately met your needs most effectively?

Answer (score 0):

Create a query like this call it say q_bill_sum

```
Select Sum(bill_total) as total, 'Bill' as Total_Type, Month(showndate) as bill_Month
From tbl_bill_total
Where Year(showndate) = 2013
group by Total_Type, Bill_month
Union
Select Sum(vat_total), 'Vat' as Total_Type, Month(showndate) as bill_month
From tbl_vat_bill_total
Where Year(showndate) = 2013 and if_paid = true
group by Total_Type, Bill_month
```

You end up with

```
1000 Bill 10
1700 Bill 11
0    Vat  10
700  Vat  11
```

then

```
Select b.Total, ifnull(v.total,0), b.bill_Month
From q_bill_sum b 
left join q_bill_sum v On v.Bill_month = b.Bill_month
```

should be close, but you never did answer my question about having vat in a month with no bill in a month.

I think anyway, access isn't my strong suit, but when I have to do a query that does a lot, I always break it down into bits, then when it works I try to streamline if it seems horrible...

Comment: sorry, I thought I did answer already. the answer is "yes" some month there will be no vat. Bill_total will have value in every month.

Comment: I've tried to execute your sql command but there was an error said "Circular reference caused by alias 'vas_total' in query definition's SELECT list."

Comment: The question again, is can there be a month with VAT but no bill, as in unpaid in November against a november bill, and then paid in December. If that can't happen, then the above should be close.

Comment: Edited query to take the alias out, should get rid of that error

Comment: after that edited, it said "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "month(showndate)" as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: The above sql that using "left join" technique works however i don't know how to add more criteria to have it display only year 2013 in that statement. Do you mind help me insert this condition to the statement ? Please.

Comment: Comment added to @joemienko's query.